# Add Twitter accounts on the /sites route?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api, sites

Would it be possible to add references to the site Twitter accounts in [the /site listing](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites)?

If your wondering what I'm talking about:
[blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/)

Comment: Hmm...  I don't know about this one.  Can you give a use case?

Comment: @Kevin: Perhaps I would use this on StackMobile - on the home page for each site, there would be a link to subscribe to the Twitter feed for that site. (Certainly a useful thing on a mobile device.)

Comment: And it's basically a feed for selected hot questions. Is there a reason not to add it?

Comment: uhm, you could infer the twitter account easily with something like *twitter.com/Stack+thirdleveldomainname*.

Comment: @Systempuntoout no that pattern doesn't work. Eg StackRobots for Electronics and robots and StackDIY for home improvement.

Comment: @Jonathan you are right, it fails also for a couple of others (diy seems correct to me).

Comment: @systempuntoout, yes I was trying to remember which don't work because my phones Internet is annoyingly slow.

Comment: @Kevin Any update on this with 1.1 out and no sign of it? It would be great if it could be added to both 1.1 and 1.0. Seeing as 1.0 stackauth is more useful.

Comment: @Jonathan - ? They've been on `/1.1/sites` since release as `twitter_account`, although many sites do not have them (any of the trilogy, any metas, StackApps, etc.).

Comment: @Kevin, very sorry I missed them on there, is there any chance of them being added to 1.0. I'm now having to decide between the pagination and the twitter links.

Comment: @Jonathan - no, nothing can be safely added to a frozen API version.

Comment: @Kevin then I dont suppose a parameter on the 1.1/sites to stop pagniation would be possible?

Comment: @Jonathan - no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it'll be really useful information, but I can't think of a good reason not to either.

<del>Will be added in a subsequent API release.</del>
Was added to `/1.1/sites` as `twitter_account` for those sites that have them.

Comment: there is a stackapps twitter account just nothing has been tweeted yet.